# How to get IP and MAC address in my C program for connected Wi-Fi user?

Tags: c, wifi, openwrt

I try to create client application that can be installed into Wi-Fi Router(OpenWRT Attitude Adjustment 12.09) 
Application must be written in C and implement OpenWRT daemon approach.
When any visitor turns Wi-Fi and connects to my SSID I need use his IP and MAC address in my C program.
How can I get IP and MAC address in my C program for any new connected users(devise)?
I started to try use arp command for any IP which already connected to router:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() 
{
    char* ip = "192.168.1.101";
    char output[255];
    char command [255];
    //system("arp -a");
    sprintf(command,"%s %s %s","arp","-a",ip);
    FILE* arp = popen(command, "r" );

    int i = 1;

    while (fgets(output, sizeof(output), arp) != 0) {
        i++;
        if ( i == 2 ) {
            printf("%s",output);
            char macAddress[18];
            int index = (int)(strchr(output,'-')-output);
            printf( "\n%d",index);
            printf ("\n----%c", output[index-2]);
            memcpy(macAddress, &output[index-2], 17);
            macAddress[17] = '\0';
            printf("\n%s",macAddress);
        }
    }

    pclose(arp);

    return 0;
}
```

`system("arp -a");`  works in Ubuntu but not for OpenWRT after Cross compile! 
Maybe I need to choose other way?

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Have you tried this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283494/get-ip-address-of-an-interface-on-linux

Comment: Yes, I have tried use this code, and I get IP or MAC for my router interface (wlan0 or eth0) But I need IP and MAC who connected to my wlan0, like I can see in luci web interface Status

Comment: Ok, now I see what you're doing. What about this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710040/arp-request-and-reply-using-c-socket-programming