# wifi - How to get connected device's name in C in openwrt?

Tags: c, wifi, openwrt

I am working on openwrt and is configured as a router. My application has to get the connected device's name and MAC ID. I referred to this link : [To get MAC ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279887/how-to-get-ip-and-mac-address-in-my-c-program-for-connected-wi-fi-user/31691811#31691811)

Can anyone suggest me how to get device's name in C?

Answer (score 0):

One of the requested information source is DHCP leases. You could for instance parse the */tmp/dhcp.leases* file.

Answer (score 0):

Use airodump-ng with your OpenWRT router. Here is some documentation on how to use it: [Airodump OpenWRT](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.tool.aircrack-ng)