# Where to free multiple mallocs

Tags: c, malloc, free, goto

I have the following piece of code:

```c
void f(size_t n) {
    int *a = malloc(n * sizeof *a);
    if(a == NULL) {
        report_error_and_exit();
    }

    int *b = malloc(n * sizeof *a);

    if(b == NULL) {
        free(a);
        report_error_and_exit();
    }

    int *c = malloc(n * sizeof *a);
    if(c == NULL) {
        free(a);
        free(b);
        report_error_and_exit();
    }

    /*use a, b, c*/
}
```

or something along those lines. Basically, I need multiple `malloc`s, and all of them mustn't fail.

I was wondering where should I free *some* of the allocated memory. As the function gets longer and bigger checking for `malloc` fails gets more messy.

A possible solution I was thinking was doing something like the following:

```c
void f(size_t n) {
    int *a = malloc(n * sizeof *a);
    if(a == NULL) {
        goto malloc_fail;
    }

    /*...*/

malloc_fail:
    free(a);
    free(b);
    /*...*/
    report_error_and_exit();
}
```

however the use of `goto` is discouraged.

I am wondering what is the appropriate solution to this.

Comment: This is a bit of an opinions based question. But IMHO that use of `goto` to jump to common clean up is one of the few cases where it is conventionally acceptable.

Comment: "the use of `goto` is discouraged" -- discouraged by whom? This is actually a pretty common idiom in C, and is probably worth considering unless your coding standard specifically forbids it.

Comment: goto is typical here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570317/what-is-the-best-way-to-free-memory-after-returning-from-an-error

Comment: But don't forget to initialize all the variables to `NULL` at the beginning.

Comment: If you're exiting the program when an error happens, you could simply not bother, since all memory is freed when the program exits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a classic example of a proper use of `goto` in C.

While it is possible to abuse `goto` (and badly), one of the cases where it does make sense is in error handling code such as this.  It only jumps forward, makes the code easier to read, and puts all of the error handling in one place so it's less error prone.

One thing you have to watch however is that if you jump over the initialization of a variable, then that variable is uninitialized.  Given your example, if the first call to `malloc` which initializes `a` fails, then your code as currently written will call `free` on `b` and `c` which are not initialized.

This can be fixed by having a different jump destination for each failure and doing the cleanup in the reverse order.

```
void f(size_t n) {
    int success = 0;

    int *a = malloc(n * sizeof *a);
    if(a == NULL) {
        goto malloc_fail_a;
    }
    int *b = malloc(n * sizeof *b);
    if(b == NULL) {
        goto malloc_fail_b;
    }
    int *c = malloc(n * sizeof *c);
    if(c == NULL) {
        goto malloc_fail_c;
    }

    /*...*/

    success = 1;

malloc_fail_c:
    free(c);
malloc_fail_b:
    free(b);
malloc_fail_a:
    free(a);
    if (!success) {
        report_error_and_exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, I was guessing that was a good use. Thanks

Comment: When using this technique, be careful not to jump over the initialization of a local variable and then use that variable, it would be easy to accidentally mix up the labels.  Another way to err on the side of caution is to declare and initialize to null all the pointers at the start; and only have the single cleanup label at the end

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a wrapper function, e.g.:

```
void f()
{
    int *a = malloc(n * sizeof *a);
    int *b = malloc(n2 * sizeof *b);
    int *c = malloc(n3 * sizeof *c);
    bool success = a && b && c;

    if ( success )
        do_stuff(a, b, c);

    free(c);
    free(b);
    free(a);

    if ( !success )
        report_error_and_exit();
}
```