# using custom deleter with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

With shared_ptr you can use a custom deleter, like:

```
auto fp = shared_ptr<FILE>( fopen("file.txt", "rt"), &fclose );
fprintf( fp.get(), "hello\n" );
```

and this will remember to `fclose` the file regardless of how the function exits. 
However, it seems a bit overkill to refcount a local variable, so I want to use `unique_ptr`:

```
auto fp = unique_ptr<FILE>( fopen("file.txt", "rt"), &fclose );
```

however, that does not compile.

Is this a defect? Is there a simple workaround? Im I missing something trivial?

Comment: [Maybe related](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/shared-ptr-and-file-for-wrapping-cstdio-update-also-dlfcn-h)

Comment: Beware of [the differences](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2415) between shared and unique pointer when it gets to deleting null pointers.

Comment: I wonder what the error message would have looked like if concepts passed. As it stands now, the error message was several pages long.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Should be

```
unique_ptr<FILE, int(*)(FILE*)>(fopen("file.txt", "rt"), &fclose);
```

since http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

or, since you use C++11, you can use `decltype`

```
std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&fclose)>
```

Comment: Using the lastest gcc compiler. I get: `In static member function ‘static std::string Helper::exec(const char*)’:
error: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘int (*)(FILE*)’ [-Werror=ignored-attributes]
`

Answer (score 12):

The above answer while its intent is OK and in practice compiles and works is wrong, because it is not specified that you are allowed to take the address of a standard library function. A C++ library implementation is allowed to provide different overloads or more parameters (with default arguments). Only calling the library function is sanctioned by the standard. Therefore, you need to wrap the call to fclose in your own function implementation or lambda, such as

```
unique_ptr<FILE, int(*)(FILE*)>(fopen("file.txt", "rt"),
   [](FILE *fp)->int{ if(fp) return ::fclose(fp); return EOF;});
```

or wait for `unique_resource`of https://wg21.link/p0052 to become standardized, but even there you need to use the lambda or a deleter function (object), see the more recent versions of p0052.

Comment: You can distinguish between overload sets by explicitly casting the function type.

Comment: does this apply also to functions from the c library?

Comment: Yes! The C Library is "imported" into the C++ standard in the global namespace and in the namespace std. If I understand it correctly the aspect of not being allowed to take the address of a library function also applies to the C library functions. For example, in <cmath> there are additional overloads added.

Comment: To be able to distinguish between function overloads when taking the address of a function does not solve the problem that you are not allowed to take the address of a standard library function. That there are overloads, does not mean that the overload that you call is actually the overload you can access through casting, it might have default arguments, which do not provide additional overloads to the set.

Comment: I would consider `&fclose` not working a defect rather than a bug.

Comment: A standard library implementation is allowed to define fclose() as a macro or to have overloads. So taking the address of a function defined in the standard library is not allowed, unless explicitly specified. That is not a defect.

Comment: The lambda expects a `int` return value, just `return ::fclose(fp):`

Comment: It **is** allowed. fclose (in stdio.h) is a **C function**, std::fclose in (cstdio) is the C++ one. C functions cannot have overloads, and even if the function is defined as a function macro, &fclose will return the address of the original, because it has no parentheses (just like &getc and &putc is legal in C, even though they can be macros).

Comment: Unfortunately Evan Dark, that is not actually true regarding to the C++ standard. While C++ provides all the stdio.h functions in the global namespace, the standard does not guarantee that you can take their addresses. The reason for that is to give implementors of the standard library leeway. On many systems, however, taking the address of fclose works, but as I said, it is not sanctioned by ISO C++ (i.e. [headers]p6. [using.linkage]p2, and because taking address is not explicitly allowed)

Answer (score 7):

Note that in a real program [you may want to check and act upon the return value of `fclose`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1954273/9723177), which could be awkward from within a destructor: you don't get to return a value and [throwing exceptions from destructors is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/130117/9723177). Similar considerations may or may not apply for other types of pointer.

With that caveat out of the way, an alternative approach would be to specify the deleter as a functor:

```c++
struct file_deleter {
    void operator()(std::FILE* fp) { std::fclose(fp); }
};

using unique_file = std::unique_ptr<std::FILE, file_deleter>;
```

The type alias allows you to simply write:

```
unique_file f{ std::fopen("file.txt", "rt") };
```

This is more ergonomic than having to pass an additional pointer or a lambda every time you create a pointer. The use of a functor type also means that the unique_ptr does not have to carry around a separate pointer for the deleter, which allows for space savings relative to the other approaches. To see this, I use the following code:

```c++
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&fclose)> f1{ nullptr, &fclose };
    std::unique_ptr<std::FILE, void(*)(std::FILE*)> f2{
        nullptr, [](std::FILE* p) { std::fclose(p); } };
    unique_file f3{ nullptr };
    std::FILE* f4{ nullptr };

    std::cout << "sizeof(f1) = " << sizeof(f1) << '\n';
    std::cout << "sizeof(f2) = " << sizeof(f2) << '\n';
    std::cout << "sizeof(f3) = " << sizeof(f3) << '\n';
    std::cout << "sizeof(f4) = " << sizeof(f4) << '\n';
}
```

Using MSVC building for an x64 target, I get the following output:

```
sizeof(f1) = 16
sizeof(f2) = 16
sizeof(f3) = 8
sizeof(f4) = 8
```

In this specific implementation, for the case using the functor the `unique_ptr` is the same size as a raw pointer, which is not possible for the other approaches.